# Stored procedure to get the entire row when we dynamically pass the value for column name and the respective column value in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I need to write a stored procedure that accepts column name and column value dynamically and return the whole row matching with the column value dynamically.

Help me to write this!!

Thanks

Comment: What isn't working specifically?

Answer (score 0):

First   I create a procedure that takes a column and its value

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Exec_query (column1 IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   value1  IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   row_out OUT hr.employees%ROWTYPE)
           IS
             query VARCHAR2(4000) := 'select * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE '
                                     || column1
                                     || '='
                                     || value1;
             c1    SYS_REFCURSOR;
           BEGIN
               OPEN c1 FOR query;

               FETCH c1 INTO row_out;
           END;

           /
```

Here I fetch the employee record for employee_id = 100 and display the first_name. Write other columns you have by using concat operator "||" inside dbms_output.put_line()

```
           SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
           DECLARE
               v_emp_row employees%ROWTYPE;
           BEGIN
               Exec_query('employee_id', '100', v_emp_row);

               dbms_output.Put_line(v_emp_row.first_name);
           END;

           /
```

Comment: I have executed both the queries, but why it is not showing the first_name as a output.?? also I need the complete row not only the first_name..

Comment: you must use SET SERVEROUTPUT ON at the beginning ;  Also, have you tried to read and understand the program?. Can't you put a little effort and write the other columns inside the dbms_output.Put_line?

Comment: In PL/SQL you cannot display the output of the select query directly as you observe in sqlplus or other IDEs. You need to write and display the column names.

Comment: This is dangerous! What if value1 contains "test' OR (1=1 AND ROWNUM=1) AND '0' = '1" Then it will return the wring row. This might have security implications.
BTW: I think you are missing single quotes around value1.

Answer (score 0):

For performance and security reason you should use bind variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_ROW_BY_EXAMPLE
      (column1 IN VARCHAR2,
          value1  IN VARCHAR2) 
 RETURN dual%ROWTYPE IS
      result dual%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
         'SELECT * FROM dual WHERE ' || column1 || ' = :value1'
         INTO result
         USING IN value1;
    return result;
END;
```

I would advise that you check whether `column1`. contains a valid column name of your table before passing it into the string literal. Also note that there is no error handling if value1 is non unique and the query returns two rows.

It would be quite nifty to put this into a package and overload the function so you have one with value1 a VARCHAR2, one a NUMBER and one a DATE etc. Then you don't need to worry about the string representation (e.g. decimal separator and date format).